# Swift Card Ui Design

Tags: swift, xcode, user-interface, storyboard, card

I am just wondering what are a component to make a Ui design card for ios apps? cause I saw a lot of these cool card design on pinterest and I was wondering how to make it. Like what are the component to make such a design.

I surf the web and found that mostly they using the new SwiftUI to make that kinda design, but i was wondering is there any possible way to make it with just a regular Storyboard? and i still don't get it the component like is it using button that custom design with Xib or it using regular tableview or what?

If there's any good Library from cocoapods I would like to know either.

this is the type of card design that I want to ask :

[[image: card design 11]

[image]

[image]

also there's a link of the kinda same design as well that I saw from pinterest :

https://pin.it/694Q8hb

If anyone knows how to make this with a standard Storyboard, like what the components are and maybe if there are any libraries from cocoapods please let me know okay, cause i wanna make this type of design for my thesis, which I'm already half way of development and I just want to make a good design, and I think this card design type looks perfect on my apps. Cheers Guys :)

Answer (score 1):

This can be done pretty easily in SwiftUI. You can use a VStack (or LazyVStack or LazyVGrid) to set up the list view (much easier than TableViews) and then make a custom, reusable view that looks like one of the views and set it as the Label in a Button. Here's some code (simplified) to get you started:

```
import SwiftUI

struct CustomView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                print("First button pressed")
            }, label: {
                CustomRowView(buttonTitle: "First Button")
            })
            
            Button(action: {
                print("Second button pressed")
            }, label: {
                CustomRowView(buttonTitle: "Second Button")
            })
            
            Button(action: {
                print("Third button pressed")
            }, label: {
                CustomRowView(buttonTitle: "Third Button")
            })

            
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct CustomRowView: View {
    
    @State var buttonTitle: String
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(buttonTitle)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .padding(.vertical, 40)
            .background(Color.blue)
            .cornerRadius(12)
    }
}


struct CustomViewsz_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        CustomView()
    }
}
```

Comment: ahhhh okayy thanks for the answer sir, i want to use the swiftUi as well cause i think it so much better and so much easier, but since my thesis is already half way and im using storyboard so its kinda hard if i wanna start over with swiftUi, but thanks sir!

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were asking for the SwiftUI way. If you're using storyboard, you need to create a TableView or CollectionView and then make a custom cell within the tableview. FYI - it's harder and takes much more code to do it with storyboard than SwiftUI.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get the look from those images is a `UIView` with:

- A custom background
- Set the corner radius with view.layer.cornerRadius
- A shadow effect
- `UILabel`s and `UIImageView`s as children views
- Probably a custom `touchesBegan` and `touchesEnded` implementation to make it behave like a button.

The views can be contained in a tableview, removing the custom dividers and stuff.

Also:
Code reuse is your friend! Put these specifications in a reusable class that you can reuse whenever you need that design.

Comment: ahhh ookayy sir, is it a little bit easier if i just use Xib? since i can reuse that class in anywhere i want? and probably im still gonna wanna know deep about how to make it expanding when i hit one of the card

Comment: @afipermana a .xib could be useful, that would definitely be a good solution. To make it animate from the small card to a bigger view controller, you'll want a custom view controller transition.

Answer (score 0):

I am Giving you the view hierarchy I hope you understand it.

**Addressing First Screen from first Pic**

- View
- TableView
- Section 1 : User Profile
- Section 2 : Bucket

  - TableViewCell.xib

    - Header
    - CollectionView
    - CollectionViewCell1.xib
- Section 3 : Shots

  - TableViewCell.xib

    - Header
    - CollectionView
    - CollectionViewCell2.xib

**Addressing the Second Screen from first pic**

- View
- CollectionView for Options (change tableview datasource on didSelectItem)
- TableView

  - TableViewCell.xib

**Addressing Screen from Second pic**

- View

  - TableView

    - Header
    - TableViewCell

      - Label
      - CollectionView

        - CollectionViewCell

Comment: Ohhh okayy thank you sir for that breakdown of every image i ask, its really helpfull at least i know the basic of every screen....or more like every card view